# Php preloads file when folder has certain name? what?

Tags: javascript, php, html, localhost

I am making a html project. But had to use php, so updated it to that.

I have a header loaded in from a js-file, and in it, it links to another page (used to be blog.html, but now it is blog.php <- that is important to remember).

---

The problem begins here:

The header still tryes to get blog.html and  any other changes to it doesn't apear eighter. Well, first I though I might have forgotten to link to the propper js-file. But no.

Then after a lot of trial and error, I ended up copying the whole folder (the original folder was called "portfolio", now it is "portfolio - Copy" <- also important)

In this new file. It works! It is Exactly the same content of the folders. Only difference is that it goes under a different name.

My conclution is that localhost saves the js-file under the "portfolio" folder, so it doesn't update the file for some reason. But I really don't know.

(btw. I can litterially delete the js-file. And nothing happens. Then if I go into the index.html file, and Ctrl-click the script that loads the js-file. It says that there is no file at this location. But if I then delete the *completly useless* script tag, the header doesn't load. What?)

Does anyone know what could be happening. Btw if you need a little more info, I might be able to give it, but I just can't think of much else relevense here.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you refreshed the cache? Press <Ctrl-F5> under Windows. See: https://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache

Comment: Next time you should try to include some code, after all, we are programmers. Especially this part makes me wonder: _"I have a header loaded in from a js-file..."_.

Comment: When developing websites on localhost it is helpful to test in incognito mode. The cache should be forgotten each time you close the window.